# Post array of dictionary using multipart/form-data in python

Tags: python, multipartform-data

I am having an issue while posting my array to some url. The requested url only supports `content-type=multipart/form-data`.

The [documentation sample](https://intrasheets.com/docs/api/value) is in **node.js**, and it works fine. But I need to achieve it in python. After several tries I am able to send data, but it gives me error  `{"error":1,"message":"The data field must be an array"}`

Below is my code.

```
# post_data = [{"x":0,"y":0,"value":"a1"}]
post_data = [
        ('x', ("data", 0)),
        ('y', ("data", 0)),
        ('value', ("data", 'x y orange')),
]
file_data ={"data":(None, str(post_data),"application/json")}
response = requests.post(post_url,files=file_data, headers=request_headers)
print(response.text)
```

Response:

```
{"error":1,"message":"The data field must be an array"}
```

If we use `data` or `json` in post parameter it gives us following error.

```
{"error":1,"message":"The Content-Type must be multipart/form-data"}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for you quick support.

Problem has been solved by updating `file_data` variable to this

```
file_data = [
    ("data[0][x]",(None,'0')),
    ("data[0][y]",(None,'0')),
    ("data[0][value]",(None,'A1')),
]
response = requests.post(post_url, files=file_data, headers=request_headers)
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it looks, the issue is with the format of the data that you are sending. In the node.js, data is sent as an array of objects, but in your Python code, you are sending the data as a list of tuples.

Try following,

```
import json

post_data = [{"x":0,"y":0,"value":"a1"}]
data_array = []
for data in post_data:
    data_dict = {}
    for key, value in data.items():
        data_dict[key] = value
    data_array.append(data_dict)

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}

json_data = json.dumps(data_array)
response = requests.post(post_url, headers=headers, data=json_data)
print(response.text)
```

**Code is updated**

It may be server error.
Above updated code, json module is used to convert the data_array list into a JSON string. Then set the Content-Type header to multipart/form-data, which required by the server.

Comment: same "The data field must be an array" error

Comment: code updated, check again

Comment: Error: "Multipart: Boundary not found". 
Thanks for you help, problem has been solved. Answer posted.